# Adpative Listview to adjust according to screen size for UWP xaml app

Tags: xaml, uwp, adaptive-ui

Listview contents multiple item like textblock 
how can we make it the list view adaptive as per the screen resolution where the grid contains multiple boxs of listview.
Need to adjust below similar xaml page listitem and text as per sceen changes

[image]

Comment: Have you checked [`AdaptiveGridView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.uwp.ui.controls.adaptivegridview?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-stable) that from community tool?

Comment: Your XAML/what your tried ?

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, you could use [WrapPanel Xaml Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/wrappanel) to approach. you just replace the default ListView `ItemsPanelTemplate` with `WrapPanel`. For more detail you could refer the following code.

```
<ListView Name="WrapPanelContainer"
          IsItemClickEnabled="True"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PhotoTemplate}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <controls:WrapPanel Background="{ThemeResource Brush-Grey-04}"
                          Padding="0,0,0,0"
                          VerticalSpacing="5"
                          HorizontalSpacing="5" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```